# Why the argument of recursive code in 8th line is 'string[:i] + string[i + 1:]' but not 'string'

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

It's about a permutation problem. I tried to understand the code below but feel a little confusing finally.

Why the argument of  recursive code in 8th line is 'string[:i] + string[i + 1:]' but not 'string'.

I know that 'string' argument to recursive will return RuntimeError.

But why?

permutation link: https://www.codewars.com/kata/permutations/python

```
def permutations(string):
    result = set([string])
    if len(string) == 2:
        result.add(string[1] + string[0])
    elif len(string) > 2:
        for i, c in enumerate(string):
            print "1.c = %s and i is %d"%(c,i)
            for s in permutations(string[:i] + string[i + 1:]):
                print "2.string[:i] + string[i + 1:] is %s and i is %d"%((string[:i] + string[i + 1:]),i)
                result.add(c + s)
                print "3.result is %s"%result
    return list(result)
```

Comment: ... So that it removes the character at position `i`...

Answer (score 1):

Note that `string[a:b]` means a `[a b)` (including `a` and excluding `b`) substring of the string. So `string[:i] + string[i + 1:]` means the whole string without `i`th character.

Comment: Got it ! So obvious mistake. and could you explain more about it ? why remove string[i]?

Comment: @TonyWang Please refer to its algorithm. I've no idea how it works!